# Error mapping Datetime type field to .xlsx file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I map a .xlsx file and am trying to read a column that the data corresponding to it must be of type DateTime. The problem is that this data comes in the form "dd-mm-yyyy", and therefore the extension function I use does not recognize it. I need to read this value and convert it to the "dd / MM / yyyy" format. I'm trying to do the following:

```
Map(i => i.TradeDate)
   .Format(i => DateTime.ParseExact(i.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
   .WithColumnName("Data de Negociação");
```

Thus, the program assigns the value 01/01/0001. Could someone indicate a method to read values ​​in "dd-MM-yyyy" and convert to "dd / MM / yyyy"?

Comment: Do you know what an f string in python is?

Comment: No, I don't know.

Comment: Basically with an f string you can format any string to your convienience. I will post a simpler method as my answer however.

Comment: Never mind, I don't know how to convert my code to C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var input = "29-04-2020"; //dd-mm-yyyy
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uJLv3e